# PHP - SESSION's Not Working - Safari

Tags: php, mysql, session, safari

So, I have a login script. It does a simple job and creates a session if it is correct details. For some reason it works in all browsers apart from Safari.

Code:

```
//Create a new function named fetch;
function fetch($sql = false,$bind = false,$obj = false) {

    //Prepare The SQL Query;
    $query = Connect()->prepare($sql);

    //Execute Binded Query;
    $query->execute($bind);

    //While Fetching Results;
    while($result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

        //Add a row to the results respectiveley;
        $row[] = $result;

    }

    //If there are no rows;
    if(!empty($row)) {

        //Make it an object;
        $row = ($obj)? (object) $row : $row;
    } else {

        //Else row is false;
        $row = false;
    }

    //If no errors happened Make $row true;
    return $row;

}

//Create a new function named user_login;
function user_login($username = false, $password = false) {

    //Fetch for the username and password applied;
    $st = fetch("SELECT username,password,email,image FROM users WHERE username = :username",array(":username"=>$username));

    //If a row was found continue
    if($st != 0) {

        $storedhash = $st[0]['password'];

        if (password_verify($password, $storedhash)) {

            //Set a new username session and set it the username;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $st[0]['email'];
            $_SESSION['image'] = $st[0]['image'];

            if($username == 'admin') {
                $_SESSION['role'] = 'admin';
            } else {
                $_SESSION['role'] = 'user';
            }

        }

    }

    //If no errors happened Make the $valid true;
    return true;

    $dontaddtry = true;

}
```

The code above is the functions being used to fetch data and see if the data was correct e.t.c.

It is called and the login data is checked by doing: `user_login($username = 'admin', $password = '123');`

If it was correct details it saves a session. Otherwise it returns false.

This works as I said in all browsers but Safari. No other question I found here helped. They were all just common mistakes like missing exit(), commas, e.t.c.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: I don't see a session_start() anywhere.. Always provide proof it exists or else you'll get downvoted and no good answers for your question.

Comment: Yes, It's there, Just the code I have above is just the main code used.@JohnConde